# What is the simplest way I can build a blockchain app using embark framework?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, embark

What is the simplest way I can build a blockchain app using embark framework? where does it store the data if I don't use IPFS? How do I run it on multiple instances in my machine for testing?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the simplest way I can build a blockchain app using embark framework?

The simplest way to get started is to follow the `embark demo` example as [described](https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework#usage---demo) in the documentation.

If you are looking for a step by step tutorial, [here](https://medium.com/@iurimatias/how-to-create-a-token-factory-with-ethereum-part-1-85e84d1f38fc) is a good example of one.

> where does it store the data if I don't use IPFS?

The use of IPFS is optional, is just one of the many stack components available in Embark. If you use IPFS, you can use it to store certain data such as photos, files, etc.. and/or to store the whole dapp itself so it's fully decentralized. If you don't want to use IPFS, you can store some limited amount data on the blockchain but nothing as complex as what you store in IPFS or something like Swarm.

> How do I run it on multiple instances in my machine for testing?

It depends on what you mean here (IPFS, blockchain, Dapp)? for the blockchain you can configure more environments in `config/blockchain.json` with the same networkId and run several instances. for the DApp itself, you can simply open the dapp in different browser dapps and then use something like metamask to interact with it using different accounts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I need is to set up multiple nodes locally on my machine in order to observe how the blockchain works in a network.